# Split Python Function is not working as expected

Tags: python

If I have a file (users.txt) with the following information formatted:

```
x y z(t)

x y z(t)
```

How can I write a python function that reads in the file (users.txt) and uses the `split` function to break up each line of the file into three variables:

`who` for `x`
`where` for `y`
`when_and_time` for `z(t)`

and `print`s to the screen such that the format is `who on where at when_and_time` or with the variables `x on y at z(t)`

What I have so far is:

```
user_info = open("~/users.txt").read()
for line in user_info:
    positions = line.split(',')
    who = positions[0]
    where = positions[1]
    when_and_time = positions[2]
    print(who + " on " + where + " at " + when_and_time)   # I press enter at this point
```

It gives me the prompt for more commands, at which point I press enter again and receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: you can check by printing `positions` list and see how many elements you have. And is it separated by `,`?

Comment: `read` will read entire file as string. if you want line by line use `readlines` it will give you lines

Comment: @Hackaholic That worked in conjunction with porglezomp's answer!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you're doing `split(",")`, which will split the string on comma characters. Since you appear to have formatted your string with spaces, it's not splitting it anywhere, so you only get one element in your list. You probably want to use `split()` with no argument to split on any whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

if you read file line by line will be better then you can split on spaces:

```
f=open('your_file')
for x in f:
    x=x.split()  # now here x contain all variables that are separated by space
    # do your stuff with x
```